# Logarithmic Questions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

At the beginning of an experiment, a scientist has 304 grams of radioactive goo. After 240 minutes, her sample has decayed to 19 grams.

What is the half-life of the goo in minutes?

Find a formula for , the amount of goo remaining at time .

How many grams of goo will remain after 8 minutes?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried and can share? Regards

Comment: Would "goo" behave differently than a single pure isotope?

Answer (score 2):

This is an [exponential decay](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/exponential-growth.html) problem.

- To find the half-life, solve $\frac{304}{2^n} = 19$ for $n$, which is the number of half lives through which the goo has already undergone. So the half life will be $\dfrac{240 \text{ minutes}}{n}$.

  > $n=4 \implies $ half-life = 60 minutes.
- We know that the formula will be of the form $Q_0 (\frac{1}{2})^{t/L}$, where $Q_0$ is the initial quantity, $304$ grams, and $L$ is the half-life.

  > $Q(t) = 304(\frac{1}{2})^{t/60}$.
- Simply plug $t=8$ into the formula you find from above.

  > $Q(8) = 304(\frac{1}{2})^{8/60} \approx 277.164.$

Comment: I have done that. But I am getting my answer wrong.

Comment: @user2501165 Tell me what you are getting and I will help you out. Because you attempted the problem, I added the answers in spoilers. You should, however, try to understand the problem and get it yourself instead of just looking at the answers.

Comment: Ir should be noted that another common form for the equation is $Q(t) \approx 304e^{-.011552t}$.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to remember in this kind of problems is the half-arbitrary-haft-reasonable assumption that the radioactive goo:

[image]

Decays following an exponential law. If $G(t)$ is the amount of goo at time $t$ then $$G(t)=Ce^{Dt},$$
for some constants $C$ and $D$.

Comment: That is the wrong exponential equation...

Comment: The wrong exponential equation?

Comment: This is decay, not gain.  Thus, the equation you are looking for is: $$G(t) = C(1-e^{Dt})$$
for some constant $C$ and $D$

Comment: I have never seen that equation. But as I said, it is a half-arbitrary-half-reasonable assumption. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life )

Comment: @anorton That equation will work just fine. Consider $f(t) = 304e^{-.012t}$

Comment: @amorton  For your decay equation, isn't $G(t)=0$ when $t=0$?

Comment: @User58220 Hmmm...  it appears that I have erred.  The equation I gave will tell you how much has decayed, not how much is left, methinks.  @ RGB: Sorry about that...